# Expand Container to fill remaining space in Column

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem with building a specific layout in flutter.

What I need is:
Scrollable screen, with two columns, where the first col is of certian (but dynamic) height. And the second col has part of certain (but dynamic) height and the rest of the col I want to fill remaining space.

The code structure.

```
   Row(
      children: [
       Expanded(
         child: Column(children:[
            someDynamicHeightWidgetsHere()])),
       Expanded(child: Column(children: [
            someWidgetsHere(), 
            here fill remainind space to match the first column]))
       ]  
    )
```

Comment: so basically, you want to fill your second column till the height of first column?

Comment: yes. That's what I need

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `IntrinsicHeight`, This widget only expands to its child height.
This class is useful, for example, when unlimited height is available and
you would like a child that would otherwise attempt to expand infinitely to
instead size itself to a more reasonable height.

**Example:**

```
IntrinsicHeight(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 800,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 400,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.yellow,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Exactly what I needed!